# How does WordPress determine if a paged query var is too high?

Tags: url-rewriting, query

Inspecting the rewrite rules for author archives I can see that any digit used after page/ is matched.

```
author/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$
=>
index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
```

In theory, this means the following pages are possible

- author/username/page/262/
- author/username/page/26278/
- author/username/page/26278292/

In real life if you visit these pages you'll get a 404 (unless the author has been crazy busy posting).

How does WordPress determine if the value of the `paged` query var is too high and in such cases set the 404?

Comment: I just found `WP::handle_404()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query either returns posts or it doesn't. Whether it's a non-existent page number, a non-existent category name, a non-existent post name, etc., it's all the same.

The rewrite rules is matched, which populates the query vars, which forms the query. The query is sent to the database, and the database returns some amount of posts between zero and whatever number was requested.

The only difference between all of those cases is what it does *after* it's determined to be a 404, which depends on what rewrite rule was matched. In the case that the `name` query var is populated, it tries to find the closest match with an additional `LIKE` query, and redirects there if something is found.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So in general **1)** a 404 is set when a query doesn't return posts and **2)** a 404 isn't set when a query returns posts. In the second case, should a 404 be set when the URL is something like `example.com/page-slug/page/3716151/` and there's no posts to show?

Comment: No, because there is a post to show- whatever post `page-slug` represents.

Comment: I'm wondering then what would be displayed on `example.com/page-slug/page/3716151/`? Surely we wouldn't want the same content as `example.com/page-slug/`?

Comment: It's probably a difficult concept to grasp if you're not familiar with SQL. There is no such thing as pages to the db engine, it's a calculation that happens in PHP when the query is formed. `/page/n/` is the pattern for archive pagination, the effect it would have on the query doesnt make sense when you are requesting a specific post. Singular post pagination is a different query var (`page` vs `paged`) and that pagination happens in PHP *after* the whole post is returned from the database. I'm probably not explaining this very well...

Comment: Check out `WP::handle_404()`. I think this runs after the query is run and is where 404s are set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. If you're trying to paginate a different query on a singular page, you need to run that query yourself before the template is loaded and determine on your own if a 404 should be presented.

Comment: For example, in the case of a page displaying results of a custom loop, I was hoping to understand how WordPress determines if pageslug/page/32456/ should display results or be set as a 404, or perhaps be  canonical redirected.

Comment: `pageslug/page/32456/` sets the `paged` query var, which is not relevant to a single post/page query, so it's ignored. If `pageslug` is a valid page, it'll never 404.

Comment: In that case, take author archives for example. example.com/author/username/page/282726/. The author "username" hasn't posted much so this is a 404. That makes sense to me. Contrast this behaviour with a custom WP_Query loop used on a page. Even if the custom query returns very few posts, example.com/pageslug/page/738328/ is never a 404. I'm wondering why not?

Comment: Because that's an archive query and `paged` is relevant in that case, as it's a collection of multiple posts. When that query is run, the SQL says "give me posts number x through x that meet this criteria". A single page is 1 post, so "give me posts number x through y of this single post" makes no sense. Further, WordPress has no awareness or concern of what happens in the template, regardless of what happens there. 404s are set long before the template is loaded.

Comment: With a custom WP_Query loop, a 404 isn't returned for example.com/pageslug/page/738328/ even when a custom query arg is used with rewrite rules in place (not `paged`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you're not applying the custom query arg to the main query it's irrelevant. Any query other than the main query is irrelevant. Only the main query can trigger a 404.

Comment: "Applying the custom query arg to the main query " what do you mean by that?

Comment: Hooking `pre_get_posts` and modifying the main query somehow based on the value of the custom query arg. If that modified main query results in no posts being returned, then you will get a 404. If youre adding the query arg for use in a secondary query and the main query still just loads a page, it's irrelevant.

Comment: I see! So if I add a custom query arg, say `paging`, and use it in a secondary query.. you're  saying I won't get a 404 for example.com/pageslug/page/3929276/ (where 3929276 is matched to `paging` via rewrite rules)?

Comment: Correct, only the main query matters. If you want the results of a secondary query to dictate whether or not it 404s, you need to run that query before the template is loaded, check the results, and force a 404 manually.